# Android application testing tool (Scheduler)

Tags: android, automated-tests, performance-testing

I need to test an Android application using some testing tools. I found plenty of them with record and play functions. [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/), [Silk Mobile](http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Silk-Mobile/Product-Trial) e.t.c. which can be used for 30 days trial. I found another tool named [Appium](http://appium.io/) which is an open source and used to test android apps.

What I want to have is a recorded test plan and execute it on a device at regular intervals much like a [Redrat scheduler](http://www.redrat.co.uk/) (Remote control automation). Using above mentioned tools I can obtain that but problem is I can't schedule the test. I need to manually invoke the test on the device everytime. I need much of a scheduler type of testing tool which schedules the recorded action and plays in at regular intervals so that I can know the application is behaving as per requirements.

Can anyone suggest me of any such tools available?

Comment: Well, the typical way scheduled automated jobs like testing are managed and run by  CI servers like Jenkins, Travis etc. These servers will, at regular intervals, get source code, compile it, launch the app on emulator/device, run test commands and store the reports.

Answer (score 1):

Try UI Automator for android,--http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Comment: But UI Automator tests can run on devices running Android 4.3 (API level 18) or higher. What about devices running below Android 4.3?